# How do I capture a form submission after no errors?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a form that is checking for valid fields after a user clicks submit.  It looks like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="#" name="basic_validate" id="basic_validate" />             
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Email Recipients</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="emailreceipients" id="emailreceipients" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <input type=submit value="Send" id="sendbtn" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

If an error is seen a class called: 'error' is added to the field.

How can I capture the form submission after all errors have been removed (e.g. user enters all data)

Here is the validation call that gets hit after form submission:

```
// Form Validation
$("#basic_validate").validate({
    rules:{
        required:{
            required:true
        },
        emailreceipients:{
            required:false
        }
    },
    errorClass: "help-inline",
    errorElement: "span",
    highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
        $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
    }
});
```

I've tried something like this:

```
$("#sendbtn").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($("#basic_validate").children('.control-group').hasClass('error')) {
        alert("Error Seen");
    }
    else {
        // Process Form
    }
});
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: else {
       $("#basic_validate").submit();
    }

Comment: my problem is that it's hitting the no errors seen block before submitting the form and highlighing the fields with an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery's `submit()`

```
$("#basic_validate").submit();
```

Comment: That was the missing piece, I assumed the submit button was doing this but I think my click event was intercepting it somehow...thanks!

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` was stopping the submit button from doing its thing. So we tell it to do its thing with `.submit();`

Comment: I swear I tried commenting out e.preventDefault() and saw the same results but maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

What processing do you want to do? If you just want to let the form submit naturally after it passes validation, you can just

```
return true;
```